# Compiling issue using boost mpi: Fatal error in PMPI_Errhandler_set: invalid communicator

Tags: linux, boost, installation, mpi, openmpi

I just installed boost 1.56.0 and boost.mpi following this [guide](http://particlephysicsandcode.com/2013/03/11/installing-boost-1-52-ubuntu-12-04-fedora/). However, 
I have an error when executing the first example of the Boost.mpi [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.point_to_point)

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
    mpi::communicator world;
    std::cout << "I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size()
              << "." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I successfully compile the previous program on linux with `mpic++` using the command

```
 mpic++ test.cpp -otest_mpi -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_iostreams -lboost_graph_parallel
```

Then, when doing

```
 mpirun -np 4 ./test_mpi
```

I obtain the following errors:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Errhandler_set: invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Errhandler_set(118): MPI_Errhandler_set(comm=0xb7151be0, errh=0xb71822c0) failed
PMPI_Errhandler_set(70): Invalid communicator
```

I am working on a virtual machine on which both openmpi and mpich are installed. I read somewhere else that the problem might be caused by a conflict between the two compilers. I also verified that MPI (without boost) works correctly running the "Hello, World!" script.

Do you have any idea about what is causing the error and how I can solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Pierpaolo

Comment: This does look suspiciously like a "mutliple installation" problem. You can try uninstalling one and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: The similarity between the values of `comm` and `errh` hints at your Boost library being built with Open MPI. The format of the error messages hints at your MPI runtime system being MPICH or another MPICH-based library (Intel MPI, MVAPICH, etc.) Uninstall them both, install a single MPI library and rebuild Boost and your application.